# System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctBy - any way to get this in a 4.8 Framework project?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

In an attempt to bridge between our current 4.8 Framework solution (with 100 projects in it) and .Net Core 6, I've told some projects to target both like so:

```
        <TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

This helps to reveal things that we can mostly fix, such as changing from using 4.8 framework assemblies to nuget packages such as System.Net.Http.  Hooray!

However, System.Linq has DistinctBy in .Net 6.0 but not in 4.8.    We have already implemented our own DistinctBy many years ago, and I'm happy to replace it with the Linq one (our implementation closely matches the MS one on github anyway).   However that won't work as the 4.8 compiler does not recognize it.

Is there any way to tell the 4.8 compiler/projects to use the newer version of Linq?

Comment: Wrap yours in `#if NET48` ?

Comment: No, but you can include your custom implmementation for .NET 4.8 and exclude it in .NET 6 so that your custom implementation doesn't exist when compiled in the latter.

Comment: @madreflection that did cross my mind. But it's alot of code and would look ugly.  And in a few months once we 're off 4.8 be no longer needed.  But also, after adding nuget System.Linq it seems that it's building properly, which I cannot explain!

Comment: If it's ugly, it's temporarily ugly. It's a transition. "Pardon our dust."

Comment: As a side note, 100 projects seems like a lot to have in a single solution. I imagine build times can be [unwieldy](https://xkcd.com/303/). It sounds like things have been reasonably well factored out into libraries. I suggest creating NuGet packages and deploying them to a private feed (could be a network folder if nothing else) so you can independently test and validate each library, and upgrade dependant projects as their dependencies are upgraded.

Comment: The solution takes less than 2 minutes for a complete rebuild, so not really a problem.  Most builds are partials, just a few seconds.

Comment: Build time was only a minor point. The bigger point is that you can manage dependencies better with separate packages and upgrade in a more controlled manner.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using IEqualityComparer

```cs
class StringArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string[] obj)
    {
        return obj.Aggregate(0, (hash, s) => hash ^ s.GetHashCode());
    }
}
// ...
var list = new List<string[]> { /* ... */ };
var distinct = list.Distinct(new StringArrayComparer());
```